# Unable to install executable-hooks and rubygems-bundler

Tags: ruby, installation

I installed all the packages required for setting up my system.
These two packages are not getting installed. (executable-hooks and rubygems-bundler).

Error :
Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2 for inspection.

Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.3.0/executable-hooks-1.3.2/gem_make.out

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing executable-hooks:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/ext/wrapper_installer
```

/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160412-50631-nopws9.rb extconf.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:71:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake (Errno::EACCES)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:71:in`open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:71:in `block in try_to_fix_binstubs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:69:in`map'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:69:in `try_to_fix_binstubs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:46:in`block in execute_no_wrapper'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:44:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:44:in`execute_no_wrapper'
    from extconf.rb:19:in `'
bundler 1.11.2
calabash-android 0.5.14
calabash-android 0.5.2
calabash-cucumber 0.18.2
cocoapods 0.39.0
cucumber 2.3.3
cucumber 1.3.20
diff-lcs 1.2.5
erubis 2.7.0
fuzzy_match 2.0.4
geocoder 1.3.3
haml 4.0.7
httpclient 2.7.1
httpclient 2.3.4.1
java_properties 0.0.4
nokogiri 1.6.7.2
rack 1.6.4
railties 4.2.6
rake 11.1.2

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.3.0/executable-hooks-1.3.2/gem_make.out

GEM ENV:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ssrin33/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/ssrin33/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
     - /Users/ssrin33/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/ssrin33/.rvm/bin
     - /Users/ssrin33/.rvm/bin

Please help...

Comment: Some check points: 1) Is your installation completely sane and working fine? 2) Do you have have all you need to build software in your computer?